# When should point (pt) font size be used?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any practical reasons to use “em” instead of “pt” font size units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348978/are-there-any-practical-reasons-to-use-em-instead-of-pt-font-size-units)

I always used either 'em' or 'px' unit for font sizes. Wondering when it is a good idea to use point(pt) unit?

Answer (score 3):

I use it on my print stylesheets, where the point unit actually makes sense.