# Weird sizing issues with h1 and span elements

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<h1><a href="">Windows Store<br /><span class="smallSubText">apps</span></a></h1>
```

and:

```
#windowsStoreApplications {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;

    font-size: 16pt;
    text-align: center;
    height: 182px;

    background-color: #9DCA87;
    border-top: 6px solid #AEDF66;
}


.smallSubText {
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```

As you can see, both the h1 and span are set to the same font-size - this is not how I want it but it's how I made it because I noticed that the font-sizes were not matching up to how they should be.

I made them both the same size to demonstrate that they are both the same size in code, but when you run the site and look at it - they're actually different sizes.

Is this due to some size weirdness with the h1 element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first, if you havn't declared a font-size for your h1's (and the rest) the [browser defaults will be implemented](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) which vary in size.

Second, you [should not](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) be using `pt` for your size, you should be using `px`, `em` or `%`.

```
#windowsStoreApplications h1 {
font-size:16pt; /* or preffered unit */
}
```

Comment: Why not use point? We've always used pt :( Sigh. Then what is pt for?

Comment: "The final unit of measurement that it is possible to declare font sizes in is point values (pt). Point values are only for print CSS! A point is a unit of measurement used for real-life ink-on-paper typography. 72pts = one inch. One inch = one real-life inch like-on-a-ruler. Not an inch on a screen, which is totally arbitrary based on resolution." ~ css-tricks.com - Thanks @Chris.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348978/are-there-any-practical-reasons-to-use-em-instead-of-pt-font-size-units

Comment: But what if we want out whole site printed? Then we should use pt? But then if we do it all in pt anyway - we achieve the same result. What's the _real_ difference then?

Comment: Yes, you would typically have a print.css stylesheet that would do some general styling in a print-like format. I've never had to implement one as the newer browsers do a great job natively, but if your project has a reports/articles/products page or something, it's usefull.

Comment: I just had a heart attack. I changed everything to em (forgetting that I would need to use points to adjust), and everything became like Hulk lol.

Answer (score 4):

If #windowsStoreApplications is a div, then you need to delclare a #windowsStoreApplications h1{} markup in your css and style the element with font-size:16px; there. You are not selecting the h1 element otherwise.

Comment: You mean 16pt (the same size as for the `span`), not 16px, right?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are correct. I am so used to px or em's that i didn't notice. Thanks.